# Using the same page as a form landing page and as a normal page

Tags: php, html, forms, get

Picture this: You have two different pages. One is the page the form is on. The other one is used as the form's landing page (with GET statement, ex. `/newpost.php?recoverPost=115`). What you want to do is ignore all the code that is used for the form when there is no ID set. How do I achieve that? I tried with the following PHP If statements:

```
$id = $_GET['recoverPost'];
if($id != NULL)
{
//yadayada
}
```

and

```
$id = $_GET['recoverPost'];
if(isset($id))
{
//yadayada
}
```

No success. What can I do to detect whether the `?recoverPost` is set or not?

Edit: Snippet:

```
if (isset($_GET['recoverPost']))
{
    include('../includes/db_connect.php');
    $query_recover = $db->prepare("SELECT title, body, category_id, post_preview FROM deletedPosts WHERE post_id=$id");
    $query_recover->execute();
    $query_recover->bind_result($title, $body, $category_id, $post_preview);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you declare `$id`? All query string parameters are passed to the `$_GET` array, so you'd need to check if `$_GET['recoverPost']` is set.

```
if (isset($_GET['recoverPost'])) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: No success.. I've added the snippet to the main post

Comment: Well, this code snippet actually works, you can test it by yourself if you create another test file just with a echo statement inside it. Your problem is probably in another part of your code.

Comment: Indeed.... Its weird because it worked before I added the if statement (only when the form was set, not the normal page), I've changed nothing but added the if statement.. now removing the if statement and the code remains broken.. Magic. I'll check that out tomorrow, thanks.